# Sony Camera Remote API beta SDK: how to deactivate auto focus on QX10?

Tags: camera, sony

Since Sony XQ10's auto-focus can't be deactivated via its app-menu, is there a way to do so using the SDK? 
Corresponding reference [Sony Camera Remote API](https://developer.sony.com/downloads/camera-file/sony-camera-remote-api-beta-sdk/) doesn't contain any "setFocusMode" or similar. [Helper Library on GitHub](https://github.com/erik-smit/sony-camera-api/blob/master/README.md) has it...but for which cameras? Any experiences?

Cheers,

Lara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently supported in the Camera Remote API SDK.  There is an update planned for spring which will include additional features but not sure about auto-focus control:

https://developer.sony.com/2014/02/24/new-cameras-now-support-camera-remote-api-beta-new-api-features-coming-this-spring-to-selected-cameras/

Keep checking https://developer.sony.com/ for updates on the API!

Answer (score 0):

Just checked Camera Remote API Reference Febr 2017 (Beta) for a possibility to set or get the focus position through the api. Seems it's still not supported.